# Count results by column

Tags: mysql

I have a large table with many columns. I need to output the name of each column and the count of how many rows of data, i.e. NOT NULL for each column, something like this:

```
col_name_1   44
coln_name_2  299
...
```

Not sure why I'm having a brain freeze. The most I can think of is:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(col_name_1), 
    COUNT(col_name_2)
FROM t1
WHERE 
    col_name_1 IS NOT NULL,
    col_name_2 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: `count` only counts non-nulls so you don't need a WHERE clause; if you want to count all rows for all columns you can't filter based on any individual column.

Comment: I don't need all columns, just the ones I select. Thanks for the reminder about non-null!

Comment: The only thing I see to help you here is the information_schema.columns which contains all the column names, so you don't need to write them all down manually

Comment: You can use `SUM(col_name_1 IS NOT NULL)` to get the count of rows where that column is not null.

Comment: Your code is fine without the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COUNT(col_name)` will count the number of rows where `col_name` is not null.

You can then repeat that for all the columns you're interested in.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(col_name_1) AS col_name_1,
    COUNT(col_name_2) AS col_name_2,
    ...
FROM yourTable
```

You don't need the `WHERE` clause, because that will only count rows where ALL the columns are not null.

Comment: Why not just `COUNT(col_name_1)`?

Comment: Forgot about that